# Auto-replace for Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want some way to make an autoreplace instance in Sublime Text 3, so, when i write a specific character or string, Sublime automatically changes it to another string (predefined by me)

I'm not looking for a snipplet where you have to press tab or similar, i want something that changes it automatically.

Is it possible via some keybind or plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way to do this in Sublime is via snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at SublimeCodeIntel which provide similar functionality to IntelliSense

https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel

But there are a great many other plugins which can assist with source editing - its very subjective and dependent on the language used.

Good luck

Comment: I abandoned the idea at the end, found a better way to achieve what i was trying to achieve, but that's a good answer for the general purpose, so i'm marking it as the answer, thanks!

Comment: @Ghost what was the better way you found? I have a similar issue

Comment: Uf bro, i haven't used Sublime for many many many years. Actually, i don't even remember if i ever solved it, cause i moved to vim at that time. Check if there is some vim-like plugin, cause all the vim keybinds allow you to replace almost anything.